# PyInstaller, onefile, no console. missing bootloader error

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile my Kivy applications to a single windows exe.

A sample of my .spec file:

```
from kivy.deps import sd12, glew
exe = EXE(pyz,Tree('C:\\Users\\me\\PycharmProjects\\test\\'),
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
           *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console= False)
```

It works with a console i.e when console=True. But when i try to make it windowed the pyinstaller complains about missing "pre-compiled bootloader". I've checked my bootloader map and i have both the windows 64 and 32 bootloaders there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try [this](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bootloader-building.html#building-the-bootloader).

Comment: I used pip to install PyInstaller i seem to miss the waf file

Comment: I was missing the runw for windows 32. weird. Replaced it.

Comment: Did it work? I have the development version and I am missing the `waf` file as well. You can download the bootloader code from the [project repository](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tree/develop/bootloader). I'll also raise an issue there to either update the manual or the distribution.

Comment: I manually updated the OS files with the git OS files, worked after that

Answer (score 1):

Missing runw file in bootloader windows 32